# J4. Get children categories

Tags: joomla-4.x, category

In a custom template helper of com_content I need to get all children categories from specific category.

```
$categories = Joomla\CMS\Categories\Categories::getInstance('content');
$cat        = $categories->get($id);
return  $cat->getChildren();
```

But `getInstance` will be deprecated in J5:

> @deprecated  5.0 Use the ComponentInterface to get the categories.

Please, what is the substitution method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMS context you can get the component through the active application. The component may not necessarily support categories so it's a good idea to check if it implements the required interface:

```
$component = Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->bootComponent('content');

if (!$component instanceof Joomla\CMS\Categories\CategoryServiceInterface)
{
    // Component does not support categories. Bail here.
}

$categories = $component->getCategory();
$cat        = $categories->get($id);
return  $cat->getChildren();
```

Comment: Thanks Sharky, It's what I was looking for. I have a strange behavior: `$categories = $component->getCategory()->get($catId)->getChildren(true);` gives subcategories of $catId , but `$categories = $component->getCategory();  $categories->get($catId)->getChildren(true);` returns empty. It's right? I am doing something wrong?

Comment: In the second snippet you do not write child categories to a variable. `$categories` is still an instance of `Joomla\CMS\Categories\Categories`. I updated the answer to include full code from your question, in case that makes it clearer. Essentially, nothing changes, except the first part.